# Android : Change fragment on grid view item click

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement a calendar for Android. So I have a fragment which represents the calendar(a gridview) and I try to change the current fragment by clicking on an item of the grid.

So I've tried to put a setOnItemClickListener on the gridview :

```java
 public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener { 
    private GridView calendarView;
    private GridCellAdapter adapter;  

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false );        

        calendarView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.calendar );
        calendarView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) {
                Fragment fragment = new DayCalendarFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace( R.id.frame_container, fragment )
               .addToBackStack( null ).commit();

            }
        } );

        adapter = new GridCellAdapter( getActivity(), R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year );
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter( adapter );

        return rootView;
   }
}
```

But this doesn't work, I don't have any error but nothing happen when I click on it. My problem is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026219/replace-fragment-on-click-of-grid-view-item

Is it possible that the adapter impact the onclick method? Can I change fragment inside the adapter class?

Comment: remove  `super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );` no need

Comment: thank you, i've done it but this doesn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by changing fragment in the onClick method of the adapter class.

Here is the code I modified :

In CalendarFragment, I removed the setOnItemClickListener and I had the FragmentManager as parameter of the adapter constuctor :

```
adapter = new GridCellAdapter( getActivity(), R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year, getFragmentManager() );
```

In GridCellAdapter :

```
@Override
public void onClick( View view ) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace( R.id.frame_container, new DayCalendarFragment() )
    .addToBackStack( null )
    .commit();        
}
```

Thank you to those who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom layout for your `Gridview` then just use these properties for your all `UI` controls for custom layout which is inflated in your custom adapter class

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: Call your item click method after your adapter set in gridview